# separate values by new line and split to new row

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to separate values by new line and split to new row in SQL Server.
I have the following data

| Ticket | Agent |
| --- | --- |
| 98765 | Agent1 Agent2 Agent3 |
| 12345 | Agent4 Agent5 Agent6 |

Or as below

[image]

Now I have to convert it into the following -

| Ticket | Agent |
| --- | --- |
| 98765 | Agent1 |
| 98765 | Agent2 |
| 98765 | Agent3 |
| 12345 | Agent4 |
| 12345 | Agent5 |
| 12345 | Agent6 |

Comment: Have you tried anything? Splitting values has been asked many, many, many times before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`string_split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select t.ticket, s.value as agent
from t cross apply
     string_split(t.agent, '
') s
order by s.value;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dc148297204dfb0c5ac14c2f39448f8c) is a db<>fiddle.